# Appropriate test of conditional difference in means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

I have some quantity $X \in \mathbb{R}$, and labels $A \in \{0, 1\}$ and $B \in \{0, 1\}$ which can be thought of as a labelling of overlapping groups (i.e., an observation belongs to group $A$ if $A = 1$, and doesn't if $A = 0$). I have samples $(x_i, a_{i}, b_{i})$ and am interested in a valid test with the null hypothesis $E[X | A = 1] - E[X | B = 1] = 0$.

In the empirical sample, we can define $n_A = \sum_i I[A = 1]$ where $I$ is the indicator function, i.e. the number of samples in group A, and analogously for B.

Now, my thinking is, that samples in both groups (i.e. where $(a_i = 1, b_i = 1)$) can be excluded when $n_A = n_B$ because in that case all of those samples contribute to each expectation equally, and then an independent t-test could be performed (possibly under some additional assumptions). But it's not entirely clear what should be done in the case $n_A \neq n_B$.

I think it's still possible to compute a valid permutation test including all samples by computing the actual difference in empirical means as a test statistic, and computing the null distribution by permuting $y_i = (a_i, b_i)$ (so as not to break the dependent structure of $A$ and $B$), pairing it with $x_i$ and recomputing the empirical difference in means.

Question:

- Is the permutation test described above valid?
- Does this testing problem have a name? Keyword-finding is difficult because it's not a matched problem in the sense of the t-test, but I don't think an independent t-test is valid here.

Comment: (1) What do $n_A$ and $n_B$ refer to?  (2) Nothing can be done without knowing about $X.$ How is it observed or measured; or what is your probability model for it?  (3) One concern about just dropping some of the data is that they can provide information about the conditional variance of $X,$ not just about its conditional mean.  How to address this (if it's even an issue) depends on what you tell us about (2).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added a definition for $n_A$ and $n_B$ to the main text.

Comment: In regard to what's known about $X$, I'm not sure what would be useful to know here. Empirically, it has proved sound to assume normality within a group, but you're entirely correct that I don't know if I can assume anything about its variance.

Comment: Well, the standard way to conduct this test is with ordinary least squares regression of $X$ against $A$ and $B.$  Because you focus on a permutation test and don't mention OLS at all, it sounds like you know *something* about $X$ that would preclude this approach--but what would that be?

Comment: I'm not wholly sure that OLS would be valid here. Could you clarify how you're proposing to conduct the test?

Comment: It's the standard t-test for a linear combination of regression coefficients.  Why are you unsure OLS might be invalid?  (There can be many reasons, but you haven't articulated any.)